# ColdFusion Date Logic

Tags: coldfusion

I am embarrassed to admit that I am not the greatest when it comes to dates and date logic ColdFusion.

```
<!---checks frequency for form schedule and sets datepart. RecordType_Frequency is a column in database daily, weekly, monthly etc.--->

<CFSWITCH expression="#RecordType_Frequency#">
     <CFCASE value="Daily">
       <CFSET datepart = "d">
     </CFCASE>
     <CFCASE value="Weekly">
       <CFSET datepart = "ww">
     </CFCASE>
     <CFCASE value="Monthly">
       <CFSET datepart = "m">
     </CFCASE>
     <CFCASE value="Quarterly">
       <CFSET datepart = "q">
     </CFCASE>
     <CFCASE value="Yearly">
       <CFSET datepart = "yyyy">
     </CFCASE>
</CFSWITCH>

 <!---setting dates based on database values for when the form should schedule--->

 <!---enddate Uses the RecordType_Frequency_StartDate column from the database which is a date in the past. Coefficient is a stored db value for the frequency 1,2 etc. for could scheduled every 1 year, 2 year --->

 <cfset enddate = datediff(datepart,RecordType_Frequency_StartDate,todaydate) + Coefficient>

 <!---start date is set to current RecordType_Frequency_StartDate which is a column   value from the database--->

 <cfset startdate = RecordType_Frequency_StartDate>

 <!---sets the next start date for when the for should schedule based on historic db start date--->

 <cfset new_date = dateformat(DateADD(datepart,Coefficient,startdate),'MM-DD-YYYY')>

 <cfloop from="1" to="#enddate#" index="i">

   <cfset new_date = dateformat(DateADD(datepart,Coefficient,startdate),'MM-DD-YYYY')>

   <cfset startdate = new_date>

   <cfset diff = datediff(datepart,RecordType_Frequency_StartDate,startdate)>

   <cfif (startdate GT todaydate)>

      <cfset next_date= startdate>

  <cfoutput>

    <!---I need this output to equal the next date value that would fall based on the schedule, future date. I am seeing multiple dates and need to figure out how to capture would weould truly be the next scheduled date---> 

     Next Date = #diff# - #dateformat(next_date)#<br />

  </cfoutput>

 </cfif>

  </cfloop>
```

In summary, I have forms that are on a schedule. The start/set up date is the only date that I have to use. I need to to grab or populate the next scheduled date for the form using what information I have. Obviously the next creation date needs to fall in the future as this date will be used in conjunction with a scheduled event.

I have posted the code with comments and need help grabbing the next logical date closest to the current date that should fall in sequence.

Comment: I hate to say it but this is probably NOT clear enough to get an answer for you... maybe you could pare it down to a single use case with actual values... that show what the answer *should* be. I get a bit lost in the code above - not sure what the values are supposed to be - you know what I mean?

Comment: It seems like the only line you really need is `new_date = dateformat(DateADD(datepart,Coefficient,startdate),'MM-DD-YYYY')` - I'm not really sure what the purpose of the rest of the code (other than the switch) is. I agree with Mark - perhaps you could post some real values and try to describe what you are trying to accomplish a little better.

Answer (score 2):

http://cfquickdocs.com/#DateAdd

If all you need is the next possible date, use the dateadd() function.

For example, if you want the next weekday use: `dateadd("w", 1, now())`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your problem, then a UDF that I wrote a while back might solve your problem:

http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/2/24/EnglinshFriendly-Interval-Calculation

Among several other options for the "interval" argument, it should also accept the ones you use in your switch block.